# Jasmine Jquery Spy AJAX complete function

Tags: javascript, jquery, unit-testing, jasmine, jasmine-jquery

I am trying to write unit test to cover method A complete() block. I am able to mock ajax request using Deferred. But Deferred does not support complete() so I am getting below error 
TypeError: _this.methodB(...).complete is not a function. Please help me to cover methodB(..).complete() block.

```
    methodB: function(xURL, container) {
    var _this = this;
    return $.ajax({

    type: 'GET',
    url: xURL,
    async: false,
    dataType: 'html',
    timeout: _this.ajaxTimeOut
    })
    .fail(function(resp) {
    _this.doSomethingOnFail();
    })
    .done(function(resp, textStatus, jqXHR) {
        if (jqXHR.status === 200 && resp !== '') {
           _this.doSomethingOnDone();       
     }              
  });
},
    methodA: function(e) {
    var _this = this,
   _this.methodB(_this.refineURL, _this.$el)
   .complete(function(resp) {
    **if (resp.responseText !== undefined && 
        resp.responseText.indexOf("PRICE_DATA_AVLBL = 'false'") > -1) {
        var params1 = _this._getFilterURLParameters(_this.refineURL);
        var params2 = _this._getFilterURLParameters(_this.SUCC_URL);

        if (params1.lowerbound !== params2.lowerbound || 
            $(e.currentTarget).hasClass('js-txt-min')) {
            $txtMin.addClass('border-danger');
        } else {
            $txtMin.val(params2.lowerbound);
        }
    } else {
       _this._pageSubmit();
    }**

 });
```

}

Unit Test Code :

```
  it('validate ajax complete', function ajaxComplete(){
      spyOn($, 'ajax').and.callFake( function fake() {
      XMLHttpRequest = jasmine.createSpy('XMLHttpRequest');      
      var jqXHR = new XMLHttpRequest();
      jqXHR.status = 200;
      var dea = new $.Deferred();    
      dea.resolve('{property:value}',' ', jqXHR);
      return dea;
   });
   f.methodA();
  });
```

Comment: If you are testing `methodA`, you shouldn't be worried about the internals of `methodB`. You should be mocking methodB. See my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47037586/444610).

Answer (score 0):

**Mock dependencies**

It is important to remember that when testing a function, you mock dependencies of that function. You don't want to actually invoke those dependent functions in your tests, because you aren't testing those functions. You should be testing those functions elsewhere, and mocking their dependencies, etc.

**Your code**

With this in mind when testing `methodA`, you shouldn't care that `methodB` *makes* an ajax request. All you care about is that it *returns* some object that has a `complete` function, and that you wire up a callback correctly, etc.

**Tests**

The following (untested) code should roughly work for you, or give you a decent starting point.

```
describe('.methodA()', function() {
  var methodBResult;

  beforeEach(function() {
    methodBResult = jasmine.createSpyObj('result', ['complete']);
    spyOn(f, 'methodB').and.returnValue(methodBResult);
  });

  it('should call .methodB()', function() {
    f.refineURL = 'something for the test';
    f.$el = 'something else for the test';
    f.methodA();
    expect(f.methodB.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(f.methodB).toHaveBeenCalledWith(f.refineURL, f.$el);
  });

  it('should register a callback on complete', function() {
    f.methodA();

    expect(methodBResult.complete.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(methodBResult.complete).toHaveBeenCalledWith(jasmine.any(Function));
  });

  it('should call .doSomethingOnComplete() when the callback is invoked', function() {
    spyOn(f, 'doSomethingOnComplete');

    f.methodA();

    var callback = methodBResult.complete.calls.argsFor(1)[0];    
    callback();

    expect(f.doSomethingOnComplete.calls.count()).toBe(1);
    expect(f.doSomethingOnComplete).toHaveBeenCalledWith();
  });
});
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. this is good starting point. I am trying to cover code in complete block which uses resp.responseText to check its empty or not.

Comment: Your question is a bit misleading then. You said you are trying to cover methodA(). This method is the only method that uses a `complete` block. It sounds like you are really trying to cover methodB(). Your example also does nothing with `resp` in the complete block.

Comment: Sorry for not including code in complete block. I am pretty new to stackoverflow. This is the code in complete block which i need to cover..complete(function(resp) {
 if (resp.responseText !== undefined &&   resp.responseText.indexOf("PRICE_DATA_AVLBL =  'false'") > -1) {
 }
}

Comment: I need to cover if condition in complete block. So i am looking for solution to cover this block. I tried to use Deferred but it does not support complete block. Any help is really appreciated. thanks again for looking into this @seth flowers.

Comment: No worries, please update your question with the code you are actually trying to test, and remove any code (like the guts of methodB) that you are not trying to test.

Comment: I have updated .complete() block with code that needs to be covered.

Comment: Right now your complete block has no side effects, so there is nothing to test. You just have an if/else, with neither of them doing anything.

Comment: in if block text box attributes are set. I need to cover this block